# Twig debugging (I have no config.yml)

Tags: php, debugging, twig

I'm getting back into the PHP game after... a long time.
I'm looking at Twig, and need to see more of what's going on.  I've found some text that needs to go into my config.yml file.  Caveat: it's not on my system.  Does it come w/ the Twig release or do I have to install Symfony as well?  Kind of lost here.

Cheers.

EDIT: I just need {{ dump(var) }} to work.  httpd error log tells me the:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'The function "dump" does not exist in

I'm setting my Twig environment like so:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment( $loader, array(
    'cache' => '/tmp',
    'debug' => true
));
```

Comment: This question is way too broad. `config.yml` suggests you found a tutorial for Symfony2, but it's not neccessary for twig to work (it's completely standalone) and the same configuration is available via pure php. Explain what you're trying to do so we can help.

Comment: I need {{ dump(var) }} to work.
Everything I've seen (which is quite a few blog posts) states I need to update config.yml.  I'm figuring out that's now Symfony, and is stand alone.

Answer (score 6):

You need to make sure that you are using twig version 1.5 or later. It looks like you are only missing 1 piece adding the debug extension to your twig environment.

```
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
```

Here is the documentation for the dump function:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html

> The dump function is not available by default. You must add the Twig_Extension_Debug extension explicitly when creating your Twig environment:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'debug' => true,
    // ...
));
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
```

> Even when enabled, the dump function won't display anything if the debug option on the environment is not enabled (to avoid leaking debug information on a production server).